# Scala Spark collect_list() vs array()

Tags: scala, apache-spark

What is the difference between `collect_list()` and `array()` in spark using scala?

I see uses all over the place and the use cases are not clear to me to determine the difference.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Even though both [`array`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@array(colName:String,colNames:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) and [`collect_list`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@collect_list(columnName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) return an `ArrayType` column, the two methods are very different.

Method `array` combines "column-wise" a number of columns into an array, whereas `collect_list` aggregates "row-wise" on a single column typically by group (or `Window` partition) into an array, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (1, "a", "b"),
  (1, "c", "d"),
  (2, "e", "f")
).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3")

df.
  withColumn("arr", array("c2", "c3")).
  show
// +---+---+---+------+
// | c1| c2| c3|   arr|
// +---+---+---+------+
// |  1|  a|  b|[a, b]|
// |  1|  c|  d|[c, d]|
// |  2|  e|  f|[e, f]|
// +---+---+---+------+

df.
  groupBy("c1").agg(collect_list("c2")).
  show
// +---+----------------+
// | c1|collect_list(c2)|
// +---+----------------+
// |  1|          [a, c]|
// |  2|             [e]|
// +---+----------------+
```