# How to group row values into a column based on an identifier?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Please see this example; I am trying to achieve this using spark sql/spark scala, but did not find any direct solution. Please let me know if it's not possible using Spark SQL / Spark Scala, in that case I can write a java/python program by writing a file out of As-Is.

[image]

Comment: Look here from one of the SO Masters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55822462/scala-spark-collect-list-vs-array

Answer (score 0):

1. github: https://github.com/mvasyliv/LearningSpark/blob/master/src/main/scala/spark/GroupListValueToColumn.scala

   2. source code
      { 
      package spark

   import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

   object GroupListValueToColumn extends App {

   val spark = SparkSession.builder()
       .master("local")
       .appName("Mapper")
       .getOrCreate()

   case class Customer(
        cust_id: Int,
        addresstype: String
     )

   import spark.implicits._

   val source = Seq(
       Customer(300312008, "credit_card"),
       Customer(300312008, "to"),
       Customer(300312008, "from"),
       Customer(300312009, "to"),
       Customer(300312009, "from"),
       Customer(300312010, "to"),
       Customer(300312010, "credit_card"),
       Customer(300312010, "from")
     ).toDF()

   val res = source.groupBy("cust_id").agg(collect_list("addresstype"))

   res.show(false)
   //  +---------+-------------------------+
   //  |cust_id  |collect_list(addresstype)|
   //  +---------+-------------------------+
   //  |300312010|[to, credit_card, from]  |
   //  |300312008|[credit_card, to, from]  |
   //  |300312009|[to, from]               |
   //  +---------+-------------------------+

   val res1 = source.groupBy("cust_id").agg(collect_set("addresstype"))

   res1.show(false)

   //  +---------+------------------------+
   //  |cust_id  |collect_set(addresstype)|
   //  +---------+------------------------+
   //  |300312010|[from, to, credit_card] |
   //  |300312008|[from, to, credit_card] |
   //  |300312009|[from, to]              |
   //  +---------+------------------------+
   }

   }

Comment: .withColumnRenamed("collect_set(addresstype)","addresstype") - rename result column. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Since answers are being given as opposed to good googling:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
   (1, "a"),
   (1, "c"),
   (2, "e")
   ).toDF("k", "v")

val df1 = df.groupBy("k").agg(collect_list("v"))
df1.show
```